# Cannot use Firebase authentication: FIRAuth.auth does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days, I am a rookie and I am not able to find a solution. I am trying to create a user sign up and log in page using XCode 8.3.3 and am using Firebase as database.

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    //Sign Up Action for email
    @IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if emailTextField.text == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)   
        } else {
            FIRAuth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {
                print("You have successfully signed up")
                //Goes to the Setup page which lets the user take a photo for their profile picture and also chose a username

                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The part that has issue is `FIRAuth.auth`. The error says "`FIRAuth` has been renamed to Auth" and if I applied such fix, although the built became successful, I could only see nothing but a white screen. If I delete the code then I can see a normal sign in screen created earlier.

Another thing is when I type import `FirebaseAuth` a red line appeared in the suggested word list that crossed out `FirebaseAuth`, I still proceeded.

Please help. I don't know why it happens. Could there be any missing pod files? Much appreciated.

Storyboard:
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwOXK.png)

Comment: Did you configure Firebase in AppDelegate?

Comment: Try removing import FirebaseAuth.

Comment: Update your pods to Firebase SDK 4.0

Comment: Yes in AppDelegate I have FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: @ArpitJain how do I update the SDK? I tried pod update in the terminal.

Comment: Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.10)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.

Comment: Those are my current files, but the problem persists

Comment: Now use the  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FIRAuth` became a `Auth` in last `Firebase` version. [link to Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start)

```
import Firebase
```

Then, in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, initialize the `FirebaseApp` object:

```
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Now you can use in your file (also `import Firebase`)

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried, and the built was successful. But I got a white screen, not my initial signup screen

Comment: @AndrewQin have you inited rootviewcontroller?

Comment: @AndrewQin Check for navigation flow

Comment: @AndrewQin In App delegate in function func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

you need to have like self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") 
or set initial view controller in storyboard.

Comment: I have it as initial view controller

Comment: @AndrewQin Show us storyboard. I think it can be wrong constraints for example

Comment: I would love to, can you please tell me how? Also since you mentioned constraints, I could not see constraints at all in the view tab in the storyboard

Comment: @AndrewQin just make a screenshot of storyboard

Comment: just did in the post

Comment: @AndrewQin so you open app and see white screen?

Comment: Issue resolved. Needed to change build from ios 10.1 to 10.3. Thank you for the help it was very nice of you

Comment: @AndrewQin Glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line into your pod file- pod 'Firebase/Auth'. do pod install after and you should be able to do get rid of the errors regarding Auth.